# what does "center must be a 2 element sequence" mean?

Tags: python, simplegui

I am a benginger at coding and am using python, i am trying to make random circles on a frame but i got a error message saying "center must be a 2 element sequence" and with every edit i make i feel like I am getting farther from solving the problem.
i tired shortening the code, adding more points, removing some points, put alot of things inside the code and the same result with the same message. [this is the code i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3pjW.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Change `Circle([(a,b)], ...)` to `Circle((a,b), ...)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode